# Pandas counter increment after comparing two columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'd like to create a simple counter in pandas that increments by one every time a cycle is complete. This should be simple, but I can't figure it out... Here is what I would like to do, with an illustrative pandas DataFrame:

```
# Illustrative dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1], 'b':[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]})

# Initialize counter to zero
counter = 0

# Increment the counter by 1 every time 'a' == 1 and 'b' == 0
df['c'] = [counter += 1 if (df['a'] == 1) and (df['b'] == 0)]
```

I would be happy if someone showed me how to do this with pandas.apply, using a custom function. Essentially I'm looping over every record/row in the DataFrame, and comparing two columns.

I know I could probably do it with numpy.where(), and then do an expanding sum, but I'm really trying to learn how to use apply with custom functions.

Here is another method I tried, with a custom function and pandas.apply:

```
counter_list = []
counter = 0
def count_cycles(df):
    if (df['a'] == 1) and (df['b'] == 0):
        counter += 1
    counter_list.append(counter)
    return pd.Series(counter_list)
df['c'] = df.apply(count_cycles)
```

Comment: Does `(df.a.eq(1) & df.b.eq(0)).cumsum()` give you the desired output?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the output I want. Can someone please show me how to do the same thing with a custom function, and pandas.apply? I need to learn that too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by

```
df['c'] = ((df['a'] == 1) & (df['b'] == 0)).cumsum()
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the output I want. Can someone please show me how to do the same thing with a custom function, and pandas.apply? I need to learn that too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not possible with `apply` I'm afraid since it neither supports the notion of a global state to refer to (such as the current value of the counter) nor it is able to access the values of the previous row. You can do the same thing using the `for` loop but it's going to be a lot less concise and a lot slower too.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the other answers, and nobody mentioned use of the `global` keyword to access your global variable also from with Pandas Dataframe's Apply function:

```
counter_list = []
counter = 0

def count_cycles(df):

    global counter  # <-- HERE
    if (df['a'] == 1) and (df['b'] == 0):
        counter += 1
    counter_list.append(counter)
    return pd.Series(counter_list)

df['c'] = df.apply(count_cycles)
```

Is this helpful?